# Why use "would" in this sentence?

Tags: usage, modal-verbs, will-would

I'm a little confused by "would" in this sentence. Speaker A is asking a question, the B's response uses "would". In this sentence, is "would" a past form of "will?"

> **A**: What is the difference between these two sentences?
>
> - If I win this race, I will buy a big house.
> - If I won this race, I would buy a big house.
>
> **B**: Both sentences could only be said before the race. As to the
> difference in meaning, my answer (like everyone else's, in this
> case) **would be** that in the first sentence the speaker speaks as
> though he believes that it is possible that he will win the race; in
> the second, he speaks as though he believes that he will not win the
> race.

Comment: The difference is that your first example with present tense "will" is an 'open' conditional, while the one with the modal preterite "won" is a remote conditional. A remote conditional is one where the condition is not fulfilled or presented as a relatively remote possibility. An open conditional is one which is neutral as to whether the condition is or will be met.

Comment: @BillJ The OP's question isn't about the open/remote conditional sentences, but the use of "would" in "*My answer **would be** that...*"

Comment: Ah, yes. So it is!

Comment: Note that B's answer to the embedded question is wrong. "If I won this race..." could be stated during the race to express what the speaker, who might for example be just a spectator watching the race, would do in a hypothetical situation in which the speaker participated in and won the race.

Answer (score 1):

Here, "*My answer **would be**...*" is a more polite form of "My answer **is**...". They mean exactly the same thing.

It's similar to the difference between these two:

> **Can** you pass the salt?
> **Would** you pas the salt?

where the second one means the same, but is more polite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, "would" is the preterite form of "will".

One possibility is that B's answer with "would be" is an implicit conditional interpreted as "If I was asked (or "if you're asking me") , my answer would be ...".

An alternative, and more likely, interpretation is that preterite "would" is being used in a less self-assured way to express a vague element of tentativeness or diffidence.

Comment: In English, is the use of a implicit conditional more polite than uses a direct way "is?"